# Filepicker.io - server side call for stat

Tags: rest, filepicker.io

I want to get width and height of images from server side call if possible

but I can't find it in Document and even try some experiments with parameter is useless.

Is there a way to call for stat on filepicker_url through REST api?

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed. Go ahead and try out the example here:
https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#stat

You can also call the underlying call:

e.g https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG/metadata?width=true&height=true

```
{"width": 400, "height": 501}
```